# iOS: Load one childViewController when parentController loading

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have three `childViewControllers` in one `parentViewController` like iOS twitter client profile.

> [image]

I would it to load one `childViewController` once loading `parentViewController`.

Then if he tap the second button for example "Photo" base on above image, load second `chilidViewController`.

As if all `childViewControllers` have `tableViewController`, when and how do I initialize second or third `childViewControllers`?

Reason asking this question is too slow showing if load three `childViewControllers` at same.

Please give me a clue.

Comment: dont get you ... you use a tabViewController? or a custom container VC?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I'm using custom container VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all three `childViewControllers` have a `tableViewController` then you can use a common `tableView` in the `parentViewController` and then update the data source of `tableView` with data specific to each child view controller.

- create a `tableview` in the `parentViewController` with datasource and delegate set to `parentViewController`.
- add a `UISegmentedControl`
- each view will have its own data (stored in an array or obtained from network).
- in the value changed action of `UISegmentedControl` update the data source of the `tableView` in the `parentViewController` to the data of each view based on index of `UISegmentedControl`.

Comment: I will follow it! Thanks so much!

Comment: @T.Akashi Please accept my answer if you think its correct.